# Mostrar resultado de uma query em html - PHP+CodeIgniter.

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, estou tentando fazer um exemplo em codeIgniter aonde quero mostrar dados do banco de dados em formularios html.

Está é a minha query:

```
    $id_entidade = $this->session->userdata('id_entidade');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM entidade where id_entidade = '$id_entidade'");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        echo $row->nome;
        echo $row->email;}
```

Aqui ela está funcionando certa, agora gostaria de saber como mostra-lá no html.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" value="<?php echo $query->nome ;?>" />
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Mas não está funcionando, poderiam me dar dicas? Estou iniciando o estudo do framework, então caso esteja muito errado, aceito dicas de melhoria.

Obrigado a quem responder, abraço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando a estrutura MVC, mas lembrando que isto é um exemplo no qual pode ser alterado e melhorado:

No **model** voce faz isso:

```
class Entidade_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getEntidade($id_entidade){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM entidade where id_entidade = ? ", array($id_entidade))->result();
        return $query;
        }
}
```

No **controller** voce realiza uma chamada ao model:

```
public function exibeResultado(){
     $this->load->model('entidade_model');
     $dados['resultados'] = $this->entidade_model->getEntidade($this->session->userdata('id_entidade'));
     $this->load->view('sua_view', $dados);
}
```

Na sua **view** você faz assim:

```
<?php foreach ($resultados as $resultado): ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $resultado->nomeColunaBd1; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $resultado->nomeColunaBd2; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode construir sua função da seguinte forma

```
# Consulta
$this->db->where("id_entidade", $this->session->userdata('id_entidade'));
$results = $this->db->get('entidade')->result();        

# foreach de retorno
foreach($results as $valor){
    echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" value="{$valor->nome}" />';
}
```

Mas lembrando que o método correto é transpor isso entre os métodos de views, controllers e models.